# How to remove the 50 amp, 80 amp and 100 amp fuses from the positive terminal of a RAV4?

Tags: toyota, fuse, rav4

I want to check the fuses at the positive battery connection of my 1998 (first generation) Toyota RAV4. Visually, the 80a and 100a look fine, but the 50a has blue deposits and I can't tell if it's broken or not. No power is reaching my engine controller, and I've checked every other fuse and the relays, so I'd like to rule out a blown 50 amp fuse as a possible cause.

My problem is, I can't find how to remove them. Simply pulling with pliers doesn't work - first the clear plastic cover pops off, then the rest won't budge at all. It feels like I'll snap the fuses' plastic casing before they'll actually move. Curiously, wiggling it wiggles the plastic casing, but *not* the metal components inside the fuse. I can't find anything online.

There's a liftable panel on the terminal. Behind it are the connections for the three heavy duty wires. These don't seem to be related to the fuses and I can't see anything that looks like a clip (but I could be wrong).

Here's a photo of the three fuses in question. The 50A is the red one on the left. It looks like it should just pull out, but it won't budge:

[image]

Comment: Can you take a picture of the fuse from the top down without glare so I can see if the fuse is blown?

Comment: @Bob'ssockpuppet I just asked a seperate question about the fuse with just such a photo: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/29234/how-to-test-a-bolted-in-heavy-duty-50a-80a-100a-fuse-with-a-multimeter-witho

Comment: If you would disconnect the battery, you should be able to use a multimeter to check the continuity of fuse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fuse connection legs are through bolted on many of these higher amp rated fuses. To find out remove the black plastic cover below the fuses. If you find small nuts then they are the bolted in type.

BTW if the fuse links under the clear plastic windows look OK then they do not need to be replaced.

Comment: Okay, looking again I can see what looks like a metal part of the fuse on the bolt under the awkward-to-open black panel. For the 50 amp, I can't tell by looking if it's good or not, is there a way to test it with a multimeter without removing it? I'll add a pic to the question in a minute.

Comment: I asked that as a seperate question with a photo: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/29234/how-to-test-a-bolted-in-heavy-duty-50a-80a-100a-fuse-with-a-multimeter-witho